# Can i stop "beautifying" when saving views in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I can't seem to find anywhere to turn off this feature, and it applied automatically to any saved views, which is completely ruining my workflow as i use newlines to structure some pretty complicated queries. The beautifier bunches everything together and also removes every comment. I realise that i can save the sql file outside MySQL Workbench, but i would think that a database management system, should be able to manage these files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "beautifying" and what exactly is happening. Provide screenshots of the situation you have. Then explain in detail what the exact problem is and what your "workflow" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Workbench's beautifier that messes up your View code, but MySQL itself.

Comment: Ok thanks but is it not possible to have the Workbench save the original files in the views list? Seems wierd to me if this is not the case, as it would be super usefull and some queries are nearly impossible to read afterwards in mysql's own format

Comment: That would require to keep the local copy and the server copy in sync all the time. And what if the view code was changed outside of WB? Or even worse: in two places. Then you'd need text diff abilities. Not impossible, but too much work for the outcome.

Comment: Well i wish for an sql version that doesen't do these changes then :)

Comment: @MikeLischke can you elaborate please? Does MySQL need the view code to be in a certain format (with all the extra parentheses) to work?

Comment: MySQL stores view code in a minified format, with all line breaks and indentation removed.